# How to install Windows 8 as Virtualbox's (Virtual) Machine?

Tags: windows-8-preview, virtualbox

How can I install **Windows 8 Developer Preview x64** as **Virtualbox**'s (Virtual) Machine?

When I try, the system shows me an *error*... I'm running a **Windows 7 Home Basic x64 as host** system.

Thanks in advence.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this guide: http://lifehacker.com/5841065/how-do-i-install-windows-8-in-a-virtual-machine